# MailboxProcessor data serialization?

Tags: f#, recovery, mailboxprocessor

Compared to NServiceBus, MSMQ, etc. message based architectures... Is there any way to "restore backup" state of F# mailbox processor?

Or best practices to extend MailboxProcessor to enable serialization of data?

In case of e.g. some kind of hardware failure.

Comment: No, there's not. If you need fault-tolerance MSMQ is a better choice.

Comment: Using NServiceBus from F#:  https://github.com/Thorium/NServiceBusFSharp

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to "restore backup" state of F# mailbox processor?

Not built in but, of course, you can just save and reload.